# Is matlab mex function or a shared object/DLL faster?

Tags: performance, matlab, mex

I have to do some calculation in matlab. It is already implemented in a m file but runs quite slow as there are many loops. The idea is to compile native code and to use this code within matlab.

Now I have two possibilities:

- Write a shared object (.so od .dll file) that is load into matlab dynamically
- Write a C(++)-MEX function

In the first case matlab does the interface to the native datatypes etc., in the latter case I have to do it on my own. The question is now: What is faster/better? I can do both but I want to gain as much speed as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you're doing only a trivial amount of calculation in the external code then there should be no difference in performance. Use whichever is more appropriate for the task at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that there would typically be a small improvement in the loading time and function call overhead when using a MEX file, but if the number of calls is low relative to the computations that are carried out, the overall difference in performance may not be that great.

However, using a MEX file is likely to lead to more transparent, readable and maintainable code, as the function will appear as though it's a native MATLAB command. I would think that unless performance is an overriding requirement, that consideration is at least as important as speed.